# how to load date from Amazon s3 file to redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using the following code

```
copy specify_item_category from 'filename' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=key_id;aws_secret_access_key=access_key' delimiter ','
removequotes  dateformat 'DD-MM-YY';
```

It is a CSV file. My date has following format 15-07-28

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any question above. As far as I understood, you need an additional column of date need to be inserted into your table, which was not there in the csv file. If this is your scenario, below are my suggestions

> If you are uploading the csv file to S3, before uploading the file, include your necessary column in the file as `unload select *, sysdate from table blah blah blah`, then upload the file and finally copy the file to a table
>
> If you are not uploading file and you do not have any control on in unloading, then copy the data in the file to a temp file and move the data from the temp to the actual files as below

```
copy table_temp from csv;
insert into actual_table select *, sysdate from table_temp;
```

Hope this solves your problem